# CopyAndUpdateAssertion - I/O mismatch

Tags: c#, idioms, autofixture

This question pertains to the use of AutoFixture's CopyAndUpdateAssertion, found in its Idioms nuget.

Suppose one has a class similar to this one:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static readonly Foo Empty = new Foo(
        new Bar1[0], 
        new Bar2[0]);

    private readonly Bar1[] _bars1;
    private readonly Bar2[] _bars2;

    public Foo(
        Bar1[] bars1,
        Bar2[] bars2)
    {
        if (bars1 == null) 
          throw new ArgumentNullException("bars1");
        if (bars2 == null) 
          throw new ArgumentNullException("bars2");

        _bars1 = bars1;
        _bars2 = bars2;
    }

    public Bar1[] Bars1
    {
        get { return _bars1; }
    }

    public Bar2[] Bars2
    {
        get { return _bars2; }
    }

    public Foo Append(Bar1 value)
    {
        if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
        return new Foo(
            _bars1.Concat(new[] {value}).ToArray(),
            _bars2);
    }

    public Foo Append(Bar2 value)
    {
        if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
        return new Foo(
            _bars1,
            _bars2.Concat(new[] { value }).ToArray());
    }

    public bool Equals(Foo other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return _bars1.SequenceEqual(other._bars1) &&
               _bars2.SequenceEqual(other._bars2);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((Foo)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _bars1.Aggregate(0, (current, next) => current ^ next.GetHashCode()) ^
               _bars2.Aggregate(0, (current, next) => current ^ next.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

Is it possible to test the Append methods using the CopyAndUpdateAssertion, given that the input is single-valued (e.g. the 'value') and the property on the output is multi-valued (e.g. the 'Bars1' property)? If yes, which pieces of the default plumbing should be replaced and can you provide any pointers as to where I should start looking?

Comment: Would it be possible to make `Foo` an iterator of `IBar`? Then Concat (and so Append) would work OOTB, as first-class citizens.

Comment: In the particular case I'm dealing with bolting on an interface such as IBar will make casting happen on the other side (or a visitor). In any case there is little similarity between Bar1 and Bar2. The behavior invoked on them is different. I did consider it, but the benefits it would bring on this side of the calculation just make it harder on the other side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't something the `CopyAndUpdateAssertion` can address, and I'm not aware that it can be tweaked to test for something like that either.

You could come up with all sorts of variations on methods such as the `Append` methods above: Insert before instead of after. Append to a string, instead of replacing it. Add to an existing number. Etc.

That falls somewhat outside of the *copy-and-update* concept; it's *copy and update* and then something more.

Obviously, if you need methods such as the above `Append` methods a lot, they'd obviously add value, but otherwise, you could also consider a more composable approach.

First, in order to make appending to sequences a bit easier, you could consider an extension method like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Append<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T value)
{
    return source.Concat(new[] { value });
}
```

If you imagine that `Foo` already has a 'standard' `WithBars1` *copy and update* method, you could achieve the same result as:

```
var foo1 = foo.WithBars1(foo.Bars1.Append(someBar).ToArray());
```

Granted, this line of code is more complex, or more detailed, than `foo1 = foo.Append(someBar)`, but on the other hand, it needs much less test coverage because it's built from 'standard' building blocks.

---

Still, ultimately, after having done something similar in two or three code bases, it was one of the many reason that made me shift to F#, where most of this is already built-in:

```
let foo' = { foo with Bars1 = foo.Bars1 |> Array.append [| someBar |] }
```

No unit tests at all are required to support the above expression, because it exclusively uses F# language features and built-in functions.